# Server symlink doesn't map in URL

Tags: apache-2.2, symlink

I have a symlink in my main htdocs directory `/home/www/example.com/htdocs`:

```
index.php
cms (symlink)
```

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 apache myuser   32 May 22 15:33 cms -> /home/www/xyz-cms/https/cms/`

However, when I visit my site at http://www.example.com/cms I get a 404 not found.

Am I missing a step to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Apache 2 documentation,

> For security reasons, Apache will follow symbolic links only if the
>   Options setting for the relevant directory includes FollowSymLinks or
>   SymLinksIfOwnerMatch.

So you need to make sure you have FollowSymLinks in the Options setting, probably as part of the `<Directory>` container.

For example,

```
<Directory /home/www/example.com/htdocs>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Also, you'll need to make sure the permissions on `/home/www/xyz-cms/https/cms/` allow access to the user Apache is running as.